# How to do this GROUP BY with the wanted result?

Tags: sql, mysql

Basically, I have a table with all the bus stops of a route with the time_from_start value, that helps to put them in a good order.

```
CREATE TABLE `api_routestop` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `route_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `station_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `time_from_start` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `api_routestop_4fe3422a` (`route_id`),
  KEY `api_routestop_15e3331d` (`station_id`)
)
```

I want to return for each stop of a line the time to go to the next stop.

I tried with this QUERY :

```
SELECT r1.station_id, r2.station_id, r1.route_id, COUNT(*), (r2.time_from_start - r1.time_from_start) as time
FROM api_routestop r1
LEFT JOIN api_routestop r2 ON r1.route_id = r2.route_id AND r1.id <> r2.id
GROUP BY r1.station_id
HAVING time >= 0
ORDER BY r1.route_id, r1.time_from_start, r2.time_from_start
```

But the group by seams not to work and the result looks like :

```
+------------+------------+----------+----------+------+
| station_id | station_id | route_id | COUNT(*) | time |
+------------+------------+----------+----------+------+
| Rub01      | Sal01      |        1 |       16 |    1 |
| Lyc02      | Sch02      |        2 |       17 |    2 |
| Paq01      | PoB01      |        3 |       15 |    1 |
| LaT02      | Gco02      |        4 |       16 |    1 |
| Sup01      | Tur01      |        5 |      132 |    1 |
| Oeu02      | CtC02      |        6 |       20 |    2 |
| Ver02      | Elo02      |        7 |       38 |    1 |
| Can01      | Mbo01      |        8 |       70 |    1 |
| Ver01      | Elo01      |        9 |       77 |    1 |
| MCH01      | for02      |       10 |       77 |    1 |
+------------+------------+----------+----------+------+
```

If I do that :

```
SELECT r1.station_id, r2.station_id, r1.route_id, COUNT(*), (r2.time_from_start - r1.time_from_start) as time
FROM api_routestop r1
LEFT JOIN api_routestop r2 ON r1.route_id = r2.route_id AND r1.id <> r2.id
GROUP BY r1.station_id, r2.station_id, r1.route_id
HAVING time >= 0
ORDER BY r1.route_id, r1.time_from_start, r2.time_from_start
```

I am approching :

```
+------------+------------+----------+----------+------+
| station_id | station_id | route_id | COUNT(*) | time |
+------------+------------+----------+----------+------+
| Rub01      | Sal01      |        1 |        1 |    1 |
| Rub01      | ARM01      |        1 |        1 |    2 |
| Rub01      | MaV01      |        1 |        1 |    4 |
| Rub01      | COl01      |        1 |        1 |    5 |
| Rub01      | Str01      |        1 |        1 |    6 |
| Rub01      | Jau01      |        1 |        1 |    7 |
| Rub01      | Cdp01      |        1 |        1 |    9 |
| Rub01      | Rep01      |        1 |        1 |   11 |
| Rub01      | CoT01      |        1 |        1 |   12 |
| Rub01      | Ctr01      |        1 |        1 |   14 |
| Rub01      | FLy01      |        1 |        1 |   15 |
| Rub01      | Lib01      |        1 |        1 |   17 |
| Rub01      | Bru01      |        1 |        1 |   18 |
| Rub01      | Sch01      |        1 |        1 |   20 |
| Rub01      | Lyc01      |        1 |        1 |   22 |
| Rub01      | Res01      |        1 |        1 |   24 |
| Sal01      | ARM01      |        1 |        1 |    1 |
| Sal01      | MaV01      |        1 |        1 |    3 |
| Sal01      | COl01      |        1 |        1 |    4 |
| Sal01      | Str01      |        1 |        1 |    5 |
| Sal01      | Jau01      |        1 |        1 |    6 |
| Sal01      | Cdp01      |        1 |        1 |    8 |
| Sal01      | Rep01      |        1 |        1 |   10 |
| Sal01      | CoT01      |        1 |        1 |   11 |
| Sal01      | Ctr01      |        1 |        1 |   13 |
| Sal01      | FLy01      |        1 |        1 |   14 |
| Sal01      | Lib01      |        1 |        1 |   16 |
| Sal01      | Bru01      |        1 |        1 |   17 |
| Sal01      | Sch01      |        1 |        1 |   19 |
| Sal01      | Lyc01      |        1 |        1 |   21 |
...
3769 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

But what do I have to do to have only the first result for the same r1.station_id and r1.route_id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a lot of results back because your getting every stop joined to every other stop on the same route.

So you'll need to identify the "Next" stop as the stop that has the same route ID but has a minimum time from start later than the current one

**Update** Added routeId to the next_stop sub query to deal with the case of stations used in multiple routes

```
SELECT
    r1.station_id, 
    r2.station_id, 
    r1.route_id, 
    r2.time_from_start - r1.time_from_start as time

FROM
api_routestop r1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
         r1.station_id , r2.route_id, min(r2.time_from_start) next_time_from_start
FROM 
  api_routestop r1
  LEFT JOIN api_routestop r2 ON r1.route_id = r2.route_id AND r1.id <> r2.id
       and r2.time_from_start > r1.time_from_start
  GROUP BY r1.Station_id, r2.route_id) next_stop

ON r1.Station_id = next_stop.station_id
   and r1.route_id = next_stop.route_id
LEFT JOIN api_routestop r2 
ON r2.time_from_start = r2.next_time_from_start
    and r1.route_id = r2.route_id
AND r2.time_from_start > r1.time_from_start
```

Comment: Ok this is close, but I still have some negative time and some r2.station_id = r1.station_id

Comment: I assumed the time_from_start on a route was unique. Was this a bad assumption

Comment: Actually it was not a bad assumption. But The last stop of a line does not have a next step.

Comment: @Natim Updated the answer to a left join on api_routestop r2

Comment: There is still negatives values. What does this mean ?

Comment: Added an extra clause to ensure that you won't get negative values ` AND r2.time_from_start > r1.time_from_start` and it also won't remove records from r1

Comment: Ok thanks. I also changed `r2.next_time_from_start` with `next_time_from_start`

Comment: I get another bug. If the r1.station_id is used in 2 routes, there is only one of both returns.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT station_id, coalesce( 
   (SELECT time_from_start 
      FROM api_routestop t2 
     WHERE t2.time_from_start > t1.time_from_start 
       AND t2.time_from_start <= (SELECT time_from_start FROM api_routestop t5 WHERE t5.station_id = '4' AND t5.route_id=t1.route_id)
       AND t2.route_id = t1.route_id 
     ORDER BY t2.time_from_start LIMIT 1), time_from_start) - time_from_start AS difference 
 FROM api_routestop t1 
WHERE t1.route_id = 1
  AND t1.time_from_start >= (SELECT time_from_start FROM api_routestop t4 WHERE t4.station_id = '2' AND t4.route_id=t1.route_id)
  AND t1.time_from_start <= (SELECT time_from_start FROM api_routestop t5 WHERE t5.station_id = '4' AND t5.route_id=t1.route_id)
ORDER BY time_from_start
```

Comment: I think on MSSQL this would be the same, but (SELECT TOP 1 time_from_start FROM (.....)). And LIMIT has to removed also.

Comment: `SELECT t1.station_id, t1.route_id, ((SELECT t2.time_from_start FROM api_routestop t2 WHERE t2.time_from_start > t1.time_from_start AND t2.route_id = t1.route_id  ORDER BY t2.time_from_start LIMIT 1) - time_from_start) as time
FROM api_routestop t1
ORDER BY t1.time_from_start` This is nice, but doesn't return the code of the next stop.

Comment: Well, it seems that MySQL has a problem with nested subqueries. There is one more nested subquery to make it sure, you do ORDER BY first and than LIMIT results. As I read in somewhere on net, MySQL to ORDER BY first, thank limit results, so its safe to write it this way:

Comment: SELECT station_id,  
       coalesce(
   (SELECT time_from_start 
           FROM api_routestop t2 
          WHERE t2.time_from_start > t1.time_from_start
            AND t2.route_id = t1.route_id 
          ORDER BY t2.time_from_start  LIMIT 1),
time_from_start) - time_from_start AS difference
FROM api_routestop t1
 ORDER BY time_from_start

Comment: How can I have the starting point station_id and ending point station_id ?

Comment: This is perfect but I just need the t2.station_id. Any help ?

Comment: Sorry I din't get it. You want result for only one station?

Comment: No, I want the result for all the station and the following one on each route. But with your request, I only have the station_id from where it start but not the next station_id

Comment: Repeat subquery for time, and replace it with t2.station_id.

Answer (score 1):

Are you open to changing the schema? If so simply adding a column containing a sequential integer for all stops on route will make this query a lot easier and more efficient.

Failing that this will do it.

```
SELECT
      station_id,
      route_id,
      time_from_start, 
      time_to_next
FROM
(
SELECT
    station_id,route_id,time_from_start,
    IF( @prev <> route_id, null, @time_from_start-time_from_start ) AS time_to_next,
    @time_from_start := time_from_start,
    @prev := route_id
  FROM api_routestop
  JOIN (SELECT @time_from_start := NULL, @prev := 0) AS r
  ORDER BY route_id, time_from_start DESC
  ) t
ORDER BY route_id,time_from_start
```

Comment: @Natim - I take it you replaced `yourtable` with `api_routestop`?

Comment: @Natim - It occurred to me that the self JOIN wasn't really needed. Please see simplified version.

Comment: Same question, how can I have the starting station_id and ending station_id ?

Comment: Do you know how I can display the second station_id ?